# What is $\left|\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{10}\{n\}\right|$ supposed to be?

Tags: notation

[image]

What "11" on this clock is supposed to be?
it looks like the union symbol but I don't get it.

Comment: I want that clock.

Comment: @Karl [It can easily be arranged, for $29.50](https://www.redbubble.com/people/pokedude140/works/24403913-math-clock?frame_color=bamboo&hand_color=white&p=clock&utm_source=google&utm_medium=google_products&utm_campaign=shopping&country_code=US&gclid=Cj0KEQjw2LjGBRDYm9jj5JSxiJcBEiQAwKWAC2nivZPx6TCdpVCdBYE33OkaVAQ8GCKdkzogPIYRJE0aAr_M8P8HAQ)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It *is* a union:

$$\bigcup_{n=0}^{10} \{n\} = \{0\}\cup \{1\}\cup\ldots\cup\{10\} = \{0,1,2,\ldots,10\}$$

But then, you take the cardinality of the resulting set:
$$
\left\lvert \bigcup_{n=0}^{10} \{n\} \right\rvert
= \left\lvert \{0,1,2,\ldots,10\} \right\rvert
= 11
$$
and you get $11$, as the set contains $11$ elements.

Comment: You're too fast, beat me to it!

Comment: @Phyllotactic The joys of being idle on a Sunday.

Comment: @MohannadMaklad My personal favorite is [this clock](http://www.uncommongoods.com/images/items/18100/18145_1_1200px.jpg). Figuring out the "1" leads to quite an interesting discovery.

Comment: Very nice clock! If I want to try and figure it out, could you give me a hint as to what I'm looking for?

Comment: @ClementC. that's pure evil

Comment: It's related to the prime-counting function. @Phyllotactic

Comment: Don't understand 1 , 11 and 3 on that clock but I'm working on it!

Answer (score 2):

It's the cardinality of the union of all the singlets containing $n$.

So it's the cardinality of the set ${\{0,1,..,10}\}$ which is $11$.