Can anyone tell me what does this symbol imply?

I can't seem to recall if I have ever seen this symbol. Can anyone please tell me what it is?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)

Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2193938/42969

This question is good....I remember solving it a long time back

The $\cup_{i=1}^\infty $ is a union symbol with an index ranging from $i=1,2,...$. In relation to the sets $A_j$, you have:
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_j = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup ...$$
If your index is finite, then you are terminating your union at some point.
The statement here is that both unions are the same under the equality defined by set inclusion.
